# Use Powershell to set Print Spooled Documents First

Tags: powershell, printing

When we create printer queue by wizard the option "print spooled documents first" it’s set by default. I am trying to achieve the same with PowerShell scripting using add-printer cmdlet.

Can see the option is there with win32_printer classes.(DO_COMPLETE_FIRST)

is there any way to enable the option without using the win32_printer class.?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the `PrintManagement` module, you'll probably have to work with `Win32_Printer`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Prncnfg.vbs which is by default present in Default windows directory like:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US
```

[How to use: Prncnfg.vbs with Examples](http://www.windowscommandline.com/prncnfg-vbs/)

You can use like this:

```
cscript Prncnfg.vbs -t -S HRServer -P ColorPrinter_2 +keepprintedjobs
```

Hope it helps.